# JavaScript To Java Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""

Tags: javascript, java

Hi am trying to convert my JavaScript decrypt method to Java can't seem to be able to do it since am stuck here i am inputting the string i don't why its saying am not ...

Error Code:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:592)
    at ae.df.sux.Main.Decrypt1(Main.java:42)
    at ae.df.sux.Main.main(Main.java:7)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
```

Java Code:

```
public static String Decrypt1(String strIn) {
    String strOut = "";
    int lenIn = strIn.length();
    int i = 0;

    int A;
    int B;

    while (i < lenIn) {
        A = Integer.parseInt(strIn.substring(i, 2), 27);
        B = Integer.parseInt(strIn.substring(i + 2, 2), 27);
        strOut+= fromCharCode(A - B);
        i+=4;
    }
    return strOut;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
Decrypt1 = function (strIn) {
    var strOut = String();
    var lenIn = strIn.length;
    var i = 0;
    var numA;
    var numB;
    while (i < lenIn) {
        numA = parseInt(strIn.substr(i, 2), 27);
        numB = parseInt(strIn.substr(i + 2, 2), 27);
        strOut += String.fromCharCode(numA - numB);
        i += 4;
    }
    return strOut;
};
```

The java error line:

```
B = Integer.parseInt(strIn.substring(i + 2, 2), 27);
```

So the value is encrypted:

```
431o5m215e1e723d7o3h6f2j401j4j2d7b345k1c631o59267j3g6627531a7a385o3g5125582g592n4l1l66395d2d4b1l4i1p531m4a1f5k2g4p2e4o205h2j693j3l1f593g7d3679317832511p5i1f6l2m6i2p7f3d58305f397g3j5c1a712k4e21783c5m267d374g1o5p3b4b234p314h2l4q2n52325e3i391b44215a3d5a344q36793c74325i1a411f6h2l5i226o2i4o254e205k3c552q391g682e7b3b5h216l2e6k2o3j1b
```

It should return:

```
<flash><strToken>MICQNQGJYLUANOG</strToken><intCharID>32962493</intCharID></flash>
```

I don't know what the problem is thanks for the help.

Comment: Did you check what is the value that you're trying to parse at this line?

Comment: What is the value of strIn? It seems that it doesn't content only numbers...

Comment: Looks like `(strIn.substring(i, 2),` or `strIn.substr(i + 2, 2), ` returns a blank

Comment: What number are you expecting an empty string to be resolved to?

Comment: The value i am trying to decrypt is a encrypted text i'll edit the topic and add the value i am trying to decrypt and what it should return.   Edit added the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not all Java functions behave exactly as same as other javascript functions. You have to check what the function returns. I have modified your java code to get desired output.

```
 public static String Decrypt1(String strIn) {
    String strOut = "";
    int lenIn = strIn.length();
    int i = 0;

    int A;
    int B;
    int nextIndex = 0;
    while (i < lenIn) {
        nextIndex = i+4;
        String aStr= strIn.substring(i, i+2);
        String bStr= strIn.substring(i + 2, nextIndex);

        System.out.println("astr:"+aStr);
        System.out.println("bstr:"+bStr);
        A = Integer.parseInt(aStr, 27);
        B = Integer.parseInt(bStr, 27);

        System.out.println("A:"+A);
        System.out.println("B:"+B);

        int C = A- B;
        System.out.println("C:"+C);

        String charStr = new String(Character.toChars(C));

        System.out.println("charStr :" +charStr);


        strOut+= charStr;
        i+=4;
    }

    System.out.println("output:"+strOut);
    return strOut;
}

 output:<flash><strToken>MICQNQGJYLUANOG</strToken><intCharID>32962493</intCharID></flash>
```

Comment: Going to learn this new code you gave me just tested worked perfectly thank you very much :)